# How to fix windscribe Json object couldn't be decoded

Tags: command-line, python, json

So basically I am trying to run this VPN, windscribe. To start I am running this commond

```
sudo /etc/init.d/windscribe-cli start
```

and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "windscribe/windscribe.py", line 60, in <module>
  File "click/decorators.py", line 115, in decorator
  File "click/decorators.py", line 89, in _make_command
  File "windscribe/WSDaemonCLI.py", line 39, in __init__
  File "windscribe/WindscribeCLI.py", line 208, in __init__
  File "windscribe/WindscribeShelve.py", line 35, in __init__
  File "json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
  File "json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
  File "json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
Failed to execute script windscribe
```

and now I am not able to figure out how to fix this, I found solutions to other issues related to how to fix the, 'No Json object could be decoded', but I am not able to find where all these python files are store either. I am very new to this so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey everyone so I basically figured it out, I uninstalled it and installed it again. It worked.